# stop subprocess from printing output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following line of code.  When I run It I get the display below.  I would like for it not to display anything.  I am taking care of the print statement somewhere else in the code.  How can I suppress the output?  I have tried "capture_output=False" and "output=None" but none of these options seem to work.

```
retval = subprocess.run(["ping", "-c1", "-i0.1", "-W1", "-q", i], capture_output=False)
if retval == 0:
    alive.append(i)
```

````
--- 10.21.30.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
PING 10.21.30.2 (10.21.30.2): 56 data bytes

--- 10.21.30.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 8.974/8.974/8.974/0.000 ms
PING 10.21.30.3 (10.21.30.3): 56 data bytes

--- 10.21.30.3 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 22.444/22.444/22.444/0.000 ms
PING 10.21.30.4 (10.21.30.4): 56 data bytes

--- 10.21.30.4 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 13.443/13.443/13.443/0.000 ms
PING 10.21.30.5 (10.21.30.5): 56 data bytes

--- 10.21.30.5 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 14.399/14.399/14.399/0.000 ms
PING 10.21.30.6 (10.21.30.6): 56 data bytes```
````

Comment: You could redirect `stdout` to a file.

Answer (score 0):

adding the stdout by itself did not work, but if I changed the subprocess.run to subprocess.call with the stdout it worked.
Thanks,

Comment: Glad you found a solution. When this sort of thing happens in the future, it's also worth checking whether the process is outputting on stderr instead of (or as well as) stdout.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
subprocess.run(["ping", "-c1", "-i0.1", "-W1", "-q", i], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```